# Background-image jumps on first scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I am trying to make a simple Parallax effect for my background images, everything seems to be working, but the background image jumps on first scroll and then it works! I can't seem to figure out why it keep on jumping, Live Preview: http://loai.directory/gallery

HTML:

```
<div class="topSection parallax">
         <div class="content">
         </div>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
#page {
   background-color: #3F8AE4;
   padding-top: 80px;
   text-align: left;
}

   /*Wrappers*/
   .wrapper {
      background-color: #ffffff;
   }

   .wrapper.A {
      background-color: #EDEDED;
      border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
   }

      /*Content Container*/
      .content {
         width: 1024px;
         padding: 50px 20px;
         margin: auto;
         overflow: hidden;
         position: relative;
      }

   /*Top Section*/
   .topSection {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #3F8AE4;
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
      padding: 10px 0;
   }

.parallax {
   background: url(../images/backgruond.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   padding: 150px 0;
}
```

JS:

```
// Y axis scroll speed
var velocity = 0.5;

function update(){ 
    var pos = $(window).scrollTop(); 
    $('.topSection').each(function() { 
        var $element = $(this);
        // subtract some from the height b/c of the padding
        var height = $element.height()-0;
        $(this).css('background-position', '50%' + Math.round((height - pos) * velocity) + 'px'); 
    }); 
};

$(window).bind('scroll', update);
```

Comment: I find it all fine on latest chrome. Which browser you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `background-position` is set to `center center` by your default CSS, but then as soon as you start scrolling, it is set to `50% 50px`... So the jump comes from the vertical position changing from centered to calculated.

You can approach this from two ways, either just set your initial css to be:

```
background: url(../images/backgruond.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50px fixed;
```

because you know that that's the position it gets set to as you start to scroll,

Or, just call your `update()` function on pageload in addition to on scroll, therefore allowing the position to be calculated immediately.

For example:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', update);
update();
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked, just trying to figure out if using Fixed is good or not